# Are trains unsafe in Asia/SE Asia?

Tags: trains, safety, southeast-asia, asia

I want to travel via train from Beijing to Paris. How safe is this? Do the trains ever get held up, robbed, people kidnapped, etc?

What about in Southeast Asia--trains in Thailand, Laos, Burma, Vietnam, etc?

This seems perfectly safe to me but I'm being told that it's unsafe by someone who I don't think is as well informed as she thinks she is.

Comment: How are you planning to get this accomplished?

Comment: Not sure where friend is getting her info, but trains in Asia and SE Asia are not anymore dangerous than any other form of travel in this region.

Comment: I agree with Tom. In pretty much any country in the world, if you must travel through it, trains are probably no less safe than any other form of transport. If you're concerned about safety, probably your worry should not be trains vs other forms of transport, but rather should I go through this country or not?

Comment: @JoErNanO The second sentence reads “Do trains ever get held up, robbed, people kidnapped, etc?” How could the question be more explicit?

Comment: @Relaxed: the title simply asks "unsafe" which made me think it was about train crashes, not security

Comment: @smci You never read the actual question?

Comment: That was my initial thinking. Of course I read the question and found the 2nd,3rd sentence. I'm just suggesting you might like to disambiguate the title itself.

Answer (score 3):

From my own experience, I would say that trains are pretty safe in Asia, probably more safe than buses or taxis. I took the train from France to Beijing, and rode on many trains in China, Vietnam, Thailand and Burma. I don't think there are trains in Laos.

I never heard of any major incidents. It's possible that people steal your stuff, especially at night when you are asleep, but that can happen in France as well.

I remember in Vietnam, people would sometimes throw rocks at trains, and so the windows had wire-mesh for protection. I'm not sure how common this is nowadays.

Comment: _"I took the train from France to Beijing"_ - wow. I would love to see a travel blog for that.